# Mouse pointer stuck in drag mode when using Files and dragging-dropping

Tags: files

When using files and dragging-dropping files (while sorting files for instance), the mouse pointer regularly freezes in drag mode, and nothing seems to be working to recover control of the machine.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is **Alt+Tab** to files app and then press **Alt+F4** to close it. It releases the mouse pointer from drag mode successfully.

The question was originally solved in one of the answers to the question asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021494/mouse-is-stuck-in-drag-mode-hand-icon-cannot-click-anything-other-than-the-to).

It took me a while to discover how to unlock the situation, and not having to hard reboot to get out of it.

Comment: I have manage to do this only with Alt+F4. But  in order to work I have to close all Pantheon-Files windows.